# ODWEK Client upgrade 9.0 to 10.1, Installations on client server?

Tags: web, ondemand, websphere

Our CMOD server version is 9.5. And our ODWEK client version is 9.0, we are planning to update ODWEK client from 9.0 to 10.1.

But starting from v9.5 ODWEK is bundled along with CMOD. So do we need to install CMOD server on each host that require ODWEK?

Is there any documentation for ODWEK upgrade (Not CMOD). Our CMOD server version is going to be the same(9.5).

Highly appreciate any inputs on the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Install the base CMOD code on the ODWEK server. Just install the binary from IBM

odwek jars - ibm/ondemand/www/api

ODWEK upgrade is usually just replacing a jar file